# How to get scroll bar real width in Qt?

Tags: qt, scrollbar

I'm trying to make a custom widget, which is basically a bunch of textedits with a single vertical scroll bar on the right. To keep widget size determined, I have to find a width of the scrollbar, as texedits geometry depends on it. Simply calling scroll_bar->width(); for freshly created vertical bar returns 101, which is obviuosly wrong.

So, is there a way to determine vertical scroll bar width correctly in Qt 3.2.3?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
int w = qApp->style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_ScrollBarExtent);
```

Comment: The size of the top and bottom buttons have also this height.

Comment: Seems to be three pixels short for me, for whatever strange reason...  :(

Comment: It does seem to be 3 pixels small in Qt5 under windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a `scrollArea` and getting the scrollbar's width a few pixels short when using Hank's answer, try the following:

```cpp
int scrollBarWidth = qApp->style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_ScrollBarExtent);
scrollBarWidth += ui->scrollArea->width() - ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->width();
```

It seems that there's a small difference in size between the `scrollArea` and the `scrollAreaWidgetContents`.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found

```
vsb->sliderRect().width();
```

which happens to be correct, but it looks bad in the code, as I have no interest in slider per se.

Comment: What is `sliderRect()`? It is not a member of QScrollBar.

Comment: This relays to outdated Qt 3.2.3. It has been changes since 4.0.

Comment: Oh, yes, I missed that.